# RSpec throws an error twice, how come?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, unique

```
  it "is invalid with a duplicate email address" do
    User.create(name: 'Joe', surname: 'Tester', email: 'test2er@example.com', password: 'password123')
    user = User.new(name: 'Jane', surname: 'Tester', email: 'test2er@example.com', password: 'password123')
    user.valid?
    puts user.errors.full_messages
    expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:email)
  end
```

is my test and when I run it, I get `expected 1 errors on :email, got 2`, the `user.errors.full_messages` shows me that I get

```
Email has already been taken
Email has already been taken
```

so that's the one error twice, why is that?

Comment: Your code is confusing.. may be before this block, you have created a user with the same :email...

Comment: @ArupRakshit nope, I haven't done that.

Comment: The validation has been added twice, either because that's actually what's in your user file or user.rb is being loaded multiple times

Comment: @FrederickCheung so that could be because I have it set like so:
`validates :email, :password, presence: true, allow_nil: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true` ? Should I expect to have two errors then?

Comment: no, that in itself wouldn't do it

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the fact that there is no need to have a validation for email uniqueness when using devise. It already has this validation and therefor the error was shown twice. Removed my own validation and the test filled out as expected - with one error.